# How to improve elasticsearch ELK perf after 500+ daily shards? Shards combine? how?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have a single server ELK, and it creates daily shards. After 500+ days of shards, the perf has decreased substantially. I have replication set to 0. Can I do something to improve the performance?

Question: Is there something like merging old shards into say - monthly shards to improve performance? If yes, how do I go about doing so?

Also, when I run `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards` I see that all of them are in `STARTED` stage. Not sure if I need to do anything about it or not. I am using elasticsearch version 1.7.x, logstash 1.5.x and kibana 4.

Comment: How many shards do you have and how large they are?

Comment: @AndreiStefan There are approx 570 shards. According to the curl command above, each shard ranges between 1mb - to - 35 mb.

Comment: Your daily indices - how many primaries have they set?

Comment: curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_settings -d '{
    "index": {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    }
}' -- so that is one primary shard per day right?

Comment: **Create monthly indices instead of daily.** The shards are small enough to fit the entire's month data. You cannot merge shards. You need to reindex if you want to do something like this. And you need to think about the retention period (how long you want to keep those indices around). If the answer is "forever" then at some point in future you need to add more nodes to your cluster.

Comment: Q1: to reindex, I need to replay the original log files using logstash-forwarder except use one large file? Q2: For new daily indexes, can they also be set to go to a monthly index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112830/discussion-between-skynss-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: And you need to probably adjust something more in Logstash so that last year's data is not indexed in today's index.

Comment: thx. answered in chat. will try

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recreating a new ELK server, and replaying the logs, but before I did that, I set indexes to be 'monthly' as per @andrei Stefan's suggestion. I also run routine optimization, and its been the solution for me.